# Could someone please tweak this php code for me? Drupal code

Tags: php, drupal, taxonomy, lowercase

I found this code to work on my Drupal site. It outputs the taxonomy terms in a comma separated list.
It successfully builds my taxonomy list to look like this:

**Business, Entertainment, Leisure**

While that's great, its using the same names to link itself in the url and so I get this:

**www.yourdomain.com/category/Business**

How can I make only the term name in the url lowercase to get it like this?

**www.yourdomain.com/category/business**

I believe I have to use this: string strtolower ( string $str ) but I'm not very php savvy. So where do I start?

```
    function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

      // Taxonomy hook to show comma separated terms
      if (module_exists('taxonomy')) {
        $term_links = array();
        foreach ($vars['node']->taxonomy as $term) {
          $term_links[] = l($term->name, 'category/' . $term->name,
            array(
              'attributes' => array(
                'title' => $term->description
            )));
        }
        $vars['node_terms'] = implode(', ', $term_links);
      }

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with the `strtolower()` function, just apply it like so:

```
$term_links[] = l($term->name, 'category/' . strtolower($term->name),
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
$term_links[] = l($term->name, 'category/' . strtolower($term->name),
```

It should work perfectly.